# Creating scenarios in WireMock for different users

Tags: xcode, graphql, ui-automation, wiremock

I'm using Wiremock to mock my server and I have run into an issue. I have two users. I want to log out at one user then log in as another. I know I can do this with scenarios but my code isn't working. I'm using a GraphQl server. My code is as follows:

Logged in as User 1

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
  "newScenarioState": "User 1",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "User1"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "bodyFileName": "User1.json"
  }
}
```

Log out

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "User 1",
  "newScenarioState": "Started",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "Logout"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "bodyFileName": "Logout.json"
  }
}
```

Log in as user 2

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Log out",
  "newScenarioState": "User 2",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "User2"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "bodyFileName": "User2.json"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what the issue could be?

*Update* I figured it out! Along with the change agoff made I also needed to change the Login as user 2 status to 201 and remove new scenario from User 1 and 2. It worked after that

Log in user 1

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "User1"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "bodyFileName": "User1.json"
  }
}
```

Log out

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
  "newScenarioState": "Logout",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "Logout"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "bodyFileName": "Logout.json"
  }
}
```

Login User 2

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Log out",
  "request": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/graphql-url",
      "headers": {
          "X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME": {
              "equalTo": "User2"
          }
      }
  },
  "response": {
      "status": 201,
      "bodyFileName": "User2.json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `log out` mapping is setting the `newScenarioState` as `"Started"`, but your `user2` mapping has a `requiredScenarioState` of `"Log out"`. Updating the `log out` mapping's `newScenarioState` should resolve the issue.

```js
// log out
{
  "scenarioName": "Test scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "User 1",
  "newScenarioState": "Log out",
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. I can get it to work when the header X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME is the same. I can see the state change then but not when the header names  are different